# Why is DataPager ignoring my custom IPagedCollectionView

Tags: silverlight, paging, datapager

I've written a implementation of `IPagedCollectionView` and when I hook it to a `DataPager`, it remains empty and disabled.  I'm providing members for `IPagedCollectionView` and `ICollectionView`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, and the notifies.  What am I doing wrong?

Also is there already an implementation of `IPagedCollectionView` for silverlight that wraps around a RIA Services `EntityQuery` in order to provide server-side sorting that requests only a single page of data at a time?

Answer (score 0):

`IPagedCollectionView` must be implemented side-by-side with `ICollectionView`, not alone. I don't know what can be your problem, but you could check [this sample](http://www.simonferquel.net/blog/archive/2009/05/12/silverlight-3-paging-with-ria-controls--m-v-vm-without-domaindatasource.aspx) from Simon Ferquel.